# ngrok Cannot GET / local server up and running

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger, ngrok

I'm trying to follow [Crowdbotics' Messenger bot tutorial](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-create-your-very-own-facebook-messenger-bot-with-dialogflow-and-node-js-in-just-one-day-f5f2f5792be5), however. I did exactly as he mentioned but i am getting this.

My folder:

[image]

Okay so, first of all i run `node index.js` and get the following:

[image]

Right after that. We initialize our ngrok server by `ngrok http 5000` and get the following:

[image]

But on **EVERY** http request i get the classic `Cannot GET /`.

On the hindsight, my `index.js` only contain:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Webhook server is listening, port 5000'));
```

I can't really point out what i am doing wrong, your help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your express js code, I think you haven't define the routes to '/'

add this before the `app.listen` on the index.js file

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.js` has started a server that listens and respond to the HTTP protocol - but it does not "serve files" the same way a web server such as Apache does.

As @Yana notes, you need to explicitly set a route to do something, such as send a text response back.

If you want the `favicon.ico` file to be sent when requested, then you need to setup a [static route](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for that as part of your `index.js` code.